# Different approach for overriding variable at make launch

Tags: makefile, environment-variables, overriding

What is the best approach for overriding variable when launching `make` command?

1. `make PREFIX="/new_path"`
2. `PREFIX="/new_path" make`

I suspect that it's not exactly the same since in the first case the overriding is specified as a *parameter* of the `make` command, while in the second case (if I guess well) we use the shell definition for setting the variable then call the command `make`.

Comment: I also found this `make` documentation of interest: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, it depends on what you mean by "best".  Both are appropriate in different circumstances.

By default makefile variable assignments take precedence over environment variable settings, and command line arguments override makefile variable assignments.

So, if you want to be sure the setting you give is used, then you should always use the command line: `make PREFIX="new/path"`.  If you want to provide a default value for a makefile to use if it doesn't already have a value, you should use the environment.